# Do MMA judges score fights independently, or can they see each other's scores or discuss scoring in some way during the fight?

Tags: scoring, mma, ufc

My guess is that MMA judges score fights independently. However, Paddy Pimblett won a unanimous decision victory over Jared Gordon at UFC 282, while 23 of the 24 media outlets providing UFC 282 results and play-by-play scored the bout in favor of Gordon, which would be statistically extremely unlikely if MMA judges score fights independently.

This makes me wonder: Do MMA judges score fights independently, or can they see each other's scores or discuss scoring in some way during the fight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MMA judges score fights independently.

https://mmachannel.com/how-does-scoring-work-in-ufc-heres-a-simple-explanation/:

> How Do UFC Judges Score Fights? Each UFC event involves 3 judges who sit at different places besides the cage.

[https://www.sportskeeda.com/mma/news-big-john-mccarthy-urges-ufc-alter-seating-arrangement-judges-want-better-scores#:~:text=McCarthy%20said%3A,two%20of%20the%20judges'%20chairs](https://www.sportskeeda.com/mma/news-big-john-mccarthy-urges-ufc-alter-seating-arrangement-judges-want-better-scores#:%7E:text=McCarthy%20said%3A,two%20of%20the%20judges%27%20chairs). :

> You have two cage doors on the octagon. The judges sit in those two spots are two of the judges' chairs